# How to prevent Back button from reloading page in Backbone app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

I have a Backbone app with Rails on the back-end. Suppose you are on page `http://localhost:3000/#home` and then go to `http://localhost:3000/#collection`. When the user clicks the Back button, I want this to behave exactly like clicking a link to `http://localhost:3000/#home` or typing this URL in the address bar and pressing Enter.

However, what happens instead with the Back button is the code in the `<script>` tag in index.html is executed again:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    AudioFileApp.initialize();
  });
</script>
```

As a result, my views are not created properly (like they are if you just enter the URL and press enter). I suspect the issue is related to this turbolinks/Backbone/Rails issue, as it fixed a problem I had with a `history already started` error: https://github.com/codebrew/backbone-rails/issues/134. However, I'm still having problems with the re-initialization, and as a beginner I'm totally stumped.

Is there a way to make sure Back will behave just like accessing the prior page via a link or the address bar?

Here is the actual initialization method if that helps:

```
initialize: function() {
  var router = new AudioFileApp.Routers.Router({
    $rootEl: $('#main'),
    currentUser: new AudioFileApp.Models.User({ id: CURRENT_USER_ID })
  });

  var navbar = new AudioFileApp.Views.NavbarView();
  $('#navbar').html(navbar.render().$el);

  var audioPlayer = new AudioFileApp.Views.AudioPlayer();
  $('#audio-player').html(audioPlayer.render().$el);

  if (!Backbone.history.started) {
    Backbone.history.start();
  }

  // Listen for Back button click
  $(document).on('page:load', function () {
    Backbone.history.stop();
    Backbone.history.start();
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I didn't completely remove turbolinks.

http://blog.steveklabnik.com/posts/2013-06-25-removing-turbolinks-from-rails-4